# Can't figure out how to return a Python dict/Json as xml using Spyne

Tags: python, python-3.x, soap, spyne

I have fired up a WSGI application using Spyne for some SOAP services that I'm trying to build.

I'm absolutely new to SOAP and Spyne in general and I can't seem to figure out how to return a JSON/Python dict as XML. This is what I've done.

```
class Fruits(ServiceBase):

@rpc(_returns=Iterable(Unicode))
def fruitify(self):
    fruits  = {"apple" : "1", "orange" : ["2","3","4"]}
    return fruits
```

I think the problem lies in the decorator I'm specifying using `_returns`.

I tried reading the docs again and again but couldn't figure it out.

The response I'm getting is something like:

```
    <soap11env:Envelope xmlns:soap11env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="lets_fruit">
   <soap11env:Body>
      <tns:fruitifyResponse>
         <tns:fruitifyResult>
            <tns:string>apple</tns:string>
            <tns:string>orange</tns:string>
         </tns:fruitifyResult>
      </tns:fruitifyResponse>
   </soap11env:Body>
</soap11env:Envelope>
```

As evident, it does not have any of my `values` associated to `keys`.

Has anybody done something similar and successfully implemented this before?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out guys.

I just had to change my `_returns=Iterable(Unicode)` to `_returns=AnyDict`.

Thanks!

Comment: im getting xml and insise reponse tag an json object, why the xml structure dont return xml?.